# Problem 4 section 4.3 from Kreyszig Functional analysis book

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Can somebody please give a hint for this problem from Kreyszig book -

Let $p$ be defined on Vector Space $X$ and satisfies $p(x+y)\leq p(x) + p(y)$  and for every scalar $a$, $p(ax) = |a| p(x)$. Show that for any given $x'\in X$ there exists a linear functional $f'$ on $X$ such that $f'(x') = p(x')$  and $|f'(x)| \le p(x)$ for all $x  \in  X$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Define $f'_0$ on the span of $x'$ by $f'_0(\alpha x')=\alpha p(x')$.  Then extend using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more how to extend. I am not getting it. I am just a beginner.

Comment: Read the statement of the Hahn-Banach theorem, and show that $f'_0$ can be extended.